# First cohomological support locus of a fibration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

I have a fibration $f \colon S \longrightarrow E$, where $S$ is a compact, complex surface of general type belonging to a special class I'm studying and $E$ is an elliptic curve.

I computed the first cohomological support locus of the fibration, namely
$$V^1(\omega_S):=\{\eta \in \mathrm{Pic}^0(E) \; | \; H^1(S, \, \omega_S \otimes f^*\eta) \neq 0 \}.$$

By some general results of Simpson and other authors, I know that $V^1(\omega_S)$ is a finite union of torsion points in $\textrm{Pic}^0 E$.

However, in my case I find something stronger: $V^1(\omega_S)$ is a *subgroup* of $\textrm{Pic}^0(E)$. So I wonder whether this is a consequence of some more general statement.

Perhaps I do not know the relevant literature enough and my question might be considered trivial by the experts, anyway let me state it explicitly:

> **Question.** Consider a fibration $f \colon S \longrightarrow C$, where $S$ is a surface of general type and $g(C) \geq 1$. Under which conditions the first cohomological support locus 
>   $$V^1(\omega_S):=\{\eta \in \mathrm{Pic}^0(C) \; | \; H^1(S, \, \omega_S \otimes f^*\eta) \neq 0 \}$$
>   is a *subgroup* of $\mathrm{Pic}^0(C)$?

Notice that,  by the results quoted above, I know that in any cases $V^1(\omega_S)$ is a finite union of translates of subtori of $\mathrm{Pic}^0(C)$ by torsion points.

**EDIT.** As suggested by abx in the comment below, an easy application of Serre duality and Leray spectral sequence shows that $V^1(\omega_S)=\textrm{Pic}^0(C)$ as soon as $g(C) \geq 2$. So the question makes sense only when $g(C)=1$ (that is precisely my case).

Comment: One remark : the dual of $H^1(S, \omega _S\otimes f^*\eta ) $ is $H^1(S, f^*\eta^{-1} ) $, which contains $H^1(C,\eta ^{-1})$ by the Leray spectral sequence. So $V^1(\omega _S)=\mathrm{Pic^o}(C)$ if $g(C)\geq 2$; your question makes sense only for $g(C)=1$.

Comment: @abx: good point, thanks! In fact in my case $g(C)=1$, so I did not consider very much the higher genus case, but you are completely right.

Answer (score 1):

Francesco,

<strike>I don't mean to be picky but I suspect a typo in the way you defined $V^1(\omega_S)$. Do you really only consider $\eta\in Pic^0( C)$? But let me stick to that for now. The post edit version of your question is whether $V^1(\omega_S)=Pic^0( C)$, when $g( C) =1$ and $S$ has general type?</strike>

Following abx, dualizing and using Leray gives 
$$V^1(\omega_S) = \{\eta\in Pic^0(C)\mid H^1(f_*\omega_S\otimes \eta)=H^0(R^1f_* O_S\otimes \eta^{-1})\not=0\}\cup \{O_C\}$$

<strike>You just need $\deg f_*\omega_S > 0$ by Riemann-Roch (remember $g=1$), but I'm pretty sure it's true in your case where $S$ has general type -- this probably goes back to Viehweg. I'm away from my books, otherwise I would check.</strike>

Comment: Dear Donu, yes I only want to consider line bundles that are pullbacks from $C$, and I'm asking when $V^1(\omega_S)$ is a *subgroup* of $\rm{Pic}^0(C)$. 
You are right, one has $\deg f_*\omega_S=1$. In fact. doing calculations in my case I find
$$f_* \omega_S = \mathcal{O}_C \oplus \mathcal{E} \oplus \bigoplus \mathcal{L}_i,$$
where $\mathcal{E}$ is an irreducible vector bundle of degree $1$ and the $\mathcal{L}_i$ are line bundles. 
By using projection formula one sees that $V_1(\omega_S) = \bigcup \mathcal{L}_i^{-1} \cup \mathcal{O}_C.$

Comment: By Simpson I know that the $\mathcal{L}_i$ are *torsion* line bundles. However, in my case I find the stronger result that  $V^1(\omega_S)$ is actually a (finite) subgroup of $\rm{Pic}^0(C)$. So I wonder if there is some deeper general reason from this fact, or if it is rather a consequence of the particular geometry of my situation.

Comment: By the way, i do not understand why you claim that $\deg f_* \omega_S >0$ should imply $V^1(\omega_S) = \textrm{Pic}^0(C).$ By Riemann Roch I have
$$h^1(f_* \omega_S \otimes \eta) = h^0(f_* \omega_S \otimes \eta) - \deg f_* \omega_S,$$
and from this it does not seem to me that one can conclude anything. For instance, in my situation $\deg f_* \omega_S =1$ but $V^1(\omega_S)$ is a finite set.

Am I missing something about your answer?

Comment: Dear Francesco, OK I understand your question now. You're right, the Riemann-Roch stuff was total nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

It is a general fact that  $f_*\omega _S\cong A\oplus F$, where $A$ is an ample vector bundle and $F$ a flat unitary vector bundle (see T. Fujita, *The sheaf of relative canonical forms of a Kähler fiber space over a curve*. Proc. Japan Acad. Ser. A Math. Sci. 54 (1978), no. 7, 183–184). Since $\pi _1(E)$ is abelian $F$ is a direct sum of flat line bundles $L_i$, so $V^1(\omega _S)=\{\mathscr{O}_E,L_i\} $. But I don't see why this should be a subgroup of $\mathrm{Pic^o}(E)$ in general.

Comment: Right, this is precisely my question.

I was aware of Fujita's result, but I also computed the  $L_i$ "by hand". And I found that, surprisingly, in my case I obtain a subgroup of $\rm{Pic}^0(E)$. 

So I wonder: conversely, if the cohomological locus is a subgroup, is it possible to say something about $S$ and/or the fibration?